# how to use Runtime?

Tags: java, shell, runtime

I would like to use the commnda given below in java. I used RunTime. but with RunTime i have all the time null as a result.

```
$ cut -d. -f2,3 <<< com.tata.titi.toto
tata.titi
```

the method used in java:

```
public  void tataName() {

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                new String[] { "/bin/sh", "cut -d. -f2,3 <<< com.tata.titi.toto " });
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        File f = new File(path+ "/taname.txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f, "UTF-8");
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while ((line != null)) {
            System.out.println(line);
            writer.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();



        }

        writer.close();


    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {

    }
```

Comment: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html but i would use version with input and error stram just wait for errors on seperate thread so a process can send out few output, then errors then more output ....

Answer (score 1):

Remove `process.waitFor();`. You are running process, waiting for its termination and then try to read its output when it is too late.

If you remove this line you execute the process and read its output. I hope this will help you.

BTW, why are you doing this? You can read file line-by-line and split each line in java. This is *much* easier and cross-platform.

Comment: Some time, I will have path/com.tata.titi.toto. I don't know if it is easier to use a split. In fact i have a folder with many applicaions, named with their package like com.tata.titi.toto.apk , and the name of application is tata.titi. i would like to have a map <package, application name>

Comment: it is not the problem of wait for i used the some synthese with process.wait for an it is ok, and when i change the command, i have what i want.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html but do the error stream processing in a separate thread Why - see javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for
>   standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
>   stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

```
package utl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;    

public class ReadStreamAsync extends Thread {

    private BufferedReader is = null;
    private int toOut = 0;//0 none, 1 out, 2 err
    private boolean toSB = false;
    private StringBuffer sb = null;
    public ReadStreamAsync(BufferedReader is, int toOut, boolean toSB){
        if(is == null)throw new NullPointerException("stream is null");
        this.is = is;
        this.toSB = toSB;
        this.toOut = toOut;
        if(toSB)sb = new StringBuffer();
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            int i;
            while((i = is.read()) > -1){
                if(toOut == 1){
                    System.out.print((char)i);
                }else if(toOut ==2){
                    System.err.print((char)i);
                }
                if(toSB)sb.append((char)i);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
                    try{
                            is.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
    }

    public String getRead(){
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
         * test code
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            BufferedReader fis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/tmp/sample1.txt"));
            ReadStreamAsync t = new ReadStreamAsync(fis, 1, false);
            t.join(1000);
            System.out.println("\nAll :");
            fis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/tmp/sample1.txt"));
             t = new ReadStreamAsync(fis, 0, true);
            t.join(1000);
            System.out.println(t.getRead());

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And this is how you could use it

```
        Process proc = procBldr.start();
        //props is a java.util.properties that was previosly loaded from some stream
        System.out.println(" Cmd start f :" + cmdStartFolder);
        System.out.println(" Cmd  :" + lstCmds);
        BufferedReader isO = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader isE = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
        asynO = new com.enstage.commonutil.file.ReadStreamAsync(isO, 1, true);
        asynE = new com.enstage.commonutil.file.ReadStreamAsync(isE, 1, true);
        if("1".equals(props.getProperty("waitFor")){
            proc.waitFor();//maybe parameterize this not required everywhere only good for short processes 
        }
        String sleepAfterWait = props.getProperty("sleepAfterWait");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);//some sleep after telling windows to do things with files is good
            if(sleepAfterWait != null){
                int i = Integer.parseInt(sleepAfterWait);
                Thread.sleep(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("sleep err :" + e );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        asynE.join();
        asynO.join();
        String checkString = props.getProperty("checkString");
        System.out.println("\n done " );
        //asynE.getRead();//if you want error out as a string
        if(checkString != null){
            System.out.println("checkString :" + checkString );
            String out = asynO.getRead();
            if(out.indexOf(checkString) > -1){
                System.out.println(" Check string found!" );
            }else{
                System.err.println(" *** Check string not found ***!" );
            }
        }
```

have used it successfully to call xcopy in a .bat and other processes short and long